# ¿Como puedo manipular los margenes en C# de forma dinamica?

Tags: c#, imagen, picturebox

Me gustaria saber como se dan margenes a los pictureBox en C#, actualmente tengo este codigo:

```
    posX = posX + 100;
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
    pic.Location = new Point(posX, 50);
    pic.Name = "pic" + z;
    pic.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    pic.ImageLocation = directoriosE[z];
    pic.Margin = new Padding(100); --- deberia setear un valor al padding
```

En la ultima linea estoy haciendo una igualacion de margin a padding, pero no encontre alguna funcion que fuera como esta `new Margin(100);` y era la unica que se acercaba mas, de todos modos no me genera el seteo de los margenes como yo esperaba.

Ejemplo de la ventana actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver quisiera separar por medio de margenes cada uno de mis elementos que se genera a travez de un ciclo for.

Tambien lo realice con el siguiente codigo:

```
        Thickness margin = pic.Margin;
        margin.Left = 10;
        pic.Margin = margin;
```

Pero me salio el siguiente error:

> No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres
>   Thickness, falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado

Tambien lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
 pic.Margin = new Padding(50,50,50,50);
```

Pero de igual forma no me aplica el margen que le estoy pidiendo. Si hago un debug de mi aplicacion y me posiciono sobre mi pic en la linea donde seteo los maregenes me da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desgraciadamente en windows forms debes primero obtener el ancho de la ventana
y asignar no con margen sino con posición x,y tu elemento
o sea que a tu variable posX deberías asignarle posX= (posX+100)+10;
para que tenga ese margen
lo malo es que si cambias de tamaño la pantalla tendrías que hacer un Resize del los elementos

Comment: Gracias, ya lo habia resuelto, pero efectivamente tienes la razon debo de asignar manualmente los margenes.